# Backbone JS collection parse

Tags: javascript, parsing, collections, backbone.js

*Hi , I have some issue with parse method!!!!!*

as you can see in backbone js [document](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/backbonejs/coll_add.htm) the parse method in collection has this syntax :
***collection.parse(response, options)***

1) I want to know why we should use / override the parse method and what is the main usage of that?

2) I read some article and I get that the parse method give us the data structure for the client-side.

3 ) I really have issue for understanding the arguments of parse method .
- what is the **options** for??

can you give me an example of using parse method with two parameters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs have a nice summary:

> parse is called by Backbone whenever a collection's models are returned by the server, in fetch. The function is passed the raw response object, and should return the array of model attributes to be added to the collection. The default implementation is a no-op, simply passing through the JSON response.

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse

1) You should return an array of model attributes. If your JSON response only has this then you don't need to do anything. Typically the parse override is used simply to point inside the JSON object at the right part. For example if your response was like this:

```
{
   httpCode: 200,
   responseMessage: 'success',
   data: [ {model1}, {model2} ...]
}
```

Then you would need to override `parse` to point to the `data` key:

```
parse: function(response) {
  return response.data;
}
```

2) They meant that the `response` arg is the object which was returned by the server.

3) The second `options` arg is the `options` that was passed to the `.fetch` call. You don't need to worry about it unless you want to do some specific logic based on the URL, the HTTP method or anything else that can be passed to fetch (and [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) options and some Backbone ones like `reset`).

4)

```
parse: function(response, options) {
  // For some reason POST requests return a different data structure.
  if (options.method === 'POST') {
     return response.data;
  }

  return response;
}
```